# Python pasting multiple images to create one

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am working on an app at the moment, where I need to create an image out of 7 selections that a user makes, I have this working, but I wonder if there is a better way to do it? Currently I do this,

```
    #!/usr/bin/env

import Image

def main(   ): #{

    layer1 = Image.open("img/layer1.png");
    layer2 = Image.open("img/layer2.png");
    layer3 = Image.open("img/layer3.png");
    layer4 = Image.open("img/layer4.png");
    layer5 = Image.open("img/layer5.png");
    layer6 = Image.open("img/layer6.png");
    layer7 = Image.open("img/layer7.png");

    image  = Image.new( "RGBA", ( 704, 469 ) );

    image.paste(layer1, ( 0, 0) );

    image.save("img/new_image.png");

    base = Image.open("img/new_image.png");

    base.paste(layer2, (0,0), layer2.convert("RGBA") );

    image.save("img/new_image.png");

    base.paste(layer3, (0,0), layer3.convert("RGBA") );

    image.save("img/new_image.png");

    base.paste(layer4, (0,0), layer4.convert("RGBA") );

    image.save("img/new_image.png");

    base.paste(layer5, (0,0), layer5.convert("RGBA") );

    image.save("img/new_image.png");

    base.paste(layer6, (0,0), layer6.convert("RGBA") );

    image.save("img/new_image.png");

    base.paste(layer7, (0,0), layer7.convert("RGBA") );

    image.open("img/new_image.png");

    print image.info;

    del base;
    del image;

#}

if ( __name__ == "__main__" ): #{

    main();

#}
```

Is there a better way to do this, eventually I want to create the final image to have a random string as a name, is there a way to do this, and have the script return that name so I can use it else where?

Comment: To have a unique name you can calculate SHA1 hash of the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from PIL import Image
import glob
def main():

layers_l = glob.glob("*.png")
layers_l = map(lambda x :Image.open(x) ,layers_l)

image  = Image.new( "RGBA", ( 2048*3, 2048*3 ) )
image.save("new_image.png")
base = Image.open("new_image.png")

for layer in layers_l[1:]:
    base.paste(layer, (0,0), layer.convert("RGBA") )
    image.save("new_image.png")
    print layer

print image.info

if ( __name__ == "__main__" ): main()
```